# Handle crash when infinite recursion happens

Tags: matlab, recursion, stack-overflow

Matlab crash when infinite recursion happens , as in the following code

file: **x.m**

```
function x
     y;
end
```

file: **y.m**

```
function y
     x;
end
```

file: **script.m**

```
x;
```

if the script script.m is executed matlab crash and it must be restarted.

even if I've used try-catch, it's still crashing:

file: **script.m**

```
try
x;
catch
    error('stack-overflow');
end
```

Is there any way to handle such crash omitted from the infinite looping ?

Comment: I agree that MATLAB crashing is not a good thing, but why would you want to trigger infinite recursion in the first place?

Comment: I work on a messy code with complex condition that has a probability of doing infinite recursion, And I wanted to know how to trigger it, and I am surprised that matlab do not deal with this as an exception that it can be handled with try-catch, and that's the thing made me ask this question more than solving my work issue.

Comment: No time to test this right now, but does it make a difference if you make `script.m` into a function?

Comment: You can set the recursion limit like this: set(0, 'RecursionLimit', 1000). Don't know if it helps, but try setting it low and then maybe matlab handles the inf recursion in a gracefull way. It's worth a try

Comment: @Jonas, the file being a function or a script it doesn't matter, no change changes.

Comment: @KlausCPH, setting limit for recursion didn't change anything also.

Comment: @SamehKamal: What version of Matlab are you using? What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick trick, you can do

```
global counter;
global RecursionDepth;
counter = 0;
RecursionDepth = 1000;
```

somewhere in beginning of your code, then you can do

```
function IncrementCounterAndCheckDepth()

    global counter;
    global RecursionDepth;
    counter = counter+1;
    if counter > RecursionDepth
    error('stack-overflow');
else
disp(RecursionDepth);
    end;
    return;
```

and insert it whenever necessary to check recursion. You can even add additional info/pass some arguments to it to improve your debugging, and once you are done with debugging, you can remove all globals and define IncrementCounterAndCheckDepth() to do nothing, so performance will not be affected, and for debugging it can be inserted in a lot of places without affecting performance. If you ever need to do additional debugging, you simply turn this function back on and modify is as required to track particular issue - you know it is everywhere in your code.

Comment: But Matlab is still crashing even if `RecursionDepth` is equal to 10.

Comment: @Samh Kamal - if you add else printf as above, what happens?

Comment: Matlab still crashing and nothing appears in the command window, and something that worse being mentioned  is that after executing your code, not only matlab crashes but also matlab do not start again till I reboot my machine.

Comment: Wow... I'm sorry if that made it worse, although it is really puzling why that happens... If you put keyboard; statement inside if, or both if else so the program breakpoints inside the function, does that helps? If nothing appears in command window, it may be because it doesn't have enough time to print or something, so perhaps putting keyboard; instead of both error and disp there to enable breakpoint and checking memory status woulkd be the first step I would take next...

Comment: P.S. If thre are clear all; anywhere along the code, globals will not work, it is quick way, more accurate way of doing that would be the class with counter and RecursionDepth variables and method that does the function above, but then it needs to be passed around or attached to handles if this is gui based application, which may complicate things...